# very strange dir/file, what is?

Tags: rm, fuse

Today on backup rsync give me an error about a dir($HOME.cache/doc/by-app)

I have checked it and I see this

First I go to the dir

```
cd $HOME.cache/doc$ cd by-app/
```

I do ls and..

```
ls
/bin/ls: error while loading shared libraries: libcap.so.2: cannot read file data: Error 21
```

I do cd..

```
cd ..
```

I control the dir-tree and made command file to see what contain

```
find by-app/
by-app/
by-app/libcap.so.2
find by-app/ |parallel file
by-app/: directory
by-app/libcap.so.2: directory
```

I want to remove!

```
rm -vfr by-app/
rm: impossible to remove 'by-app/libcap.so.2': Operation not permitted
```

I did this as root!

```
sudo rm -frv .cache/doc/by-app
Password: 
rm: impossible to remove '.cache/doc/by-app': Permission denied
```

What is this?

System is Slackware64 15.0

Comment: check who owns that file.

Comment: Thanks, solution already found by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This folder/mountpoint is created by xdg-desktop-portal, which is what flatpak uses to access resources outside of the sandboxes it runs applications on: https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/desktop-integration.html#portals

Without it you may break whatever you installed via flatpak.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

Some app mount "portal" with fuse.

```
mount|grep fuse
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
gvfsd-fuse on /home/user/.cache/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
portal on /home/user/.cache/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

So if I want to rm I first do umount

```
sudo umount /home/user/.cache/doc 
find !$
find /home/user/.cache/doc
/home/user/.cache/doc
```

But I prefer investigate first which is portal, maybe I will exclude it from backup.

Comment: typically you run a backup with a tool that can be set to not walk into other mounted filesystems

Comment: The problem is another, give permission denied, but is not a real problem because I can exclude safely that dir. The backup tool is rsync

Comment: yes, that can be avoided if rsync doesn't even go into .cache (which is probably a good idea, because backing up a cache is not helpful), or into .cache/doc, and the latter is trivially achievable by telling rsync it should not cross into other mounted filesystems, as said.